# What is the this syntax in Babel compiled code?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I was reading an ES2015 primer on [this site](https://www.packtpub.com/mapt/book/Web%20Development/9781785885587/1/ch01lvl1sec9/Introduction+to+Node.js+6+and+ES2015) and this example was given for [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015):

```
const namespace = '-webkit-'; 
const style = { 
  [namespace + 'box-sizing'] : 'border-box', 
  [namespace + 'box-shadow'] : '10px10px5px #888888' 
};
```

This is pretty straightforward, but I don't understand what Babel is doing it to transpile it. It gives this:

```
var _style;
var namespace = '-webkit-';
var style = (
  _style = {},
  _style[namespace + 'box-sizing'] = 'border-box',
  _style[namespace + 'box-shadow'] = '10px 10px 5px #888888',
  _style
);
```

(I've reformatted the indentations)

[Online Babel Transpilation here](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Ces2015-loose%2Creact%2Cstage-2&code=const%20namespace%20%3D%20'-webkit-'%3B%0Dconst%20style%20%3D%20%7B%0D%20%20%5Bnamespace%20%2B%20'box-sizing'%5D%20%3A%20'border-box'%2C%0D%20%20%5Bnamespace%20%2B%20'box-shadow'%5D%20%3A%20'10px%2010px%205px%20%23888888'%2C%0D%7D%3B)

I cannot find documentation on what this syntax is: the declaration of the `_style` object, then a list in paranthesis of property names and their values, then simply ending with a`, _style` before the ending parthenthesis.

Comment: FYI, the [*comma operator*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) always existed in ECMAScript, it's not new to ES6.

Comment: Thanks @FelixKling :-) I included the reference to the comma operator in the answer now.

Comment: One does wonder why the transpiler bothers creating the `_style` object at all.  Seems a waste.  They could just initialize `var style = {};` and then add each of the properties.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In JavaScript, the expressions in parenthesis, because of the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), are executed from left-right and the result of the last expression will be returned as the result. For example,

```js
console.log(
    (console.log(1), console.log(2), 3)
);
```

would print 1, 2, and 3 in three lines. The last value `3` is returned as the result of the expression and that is printed by the outer `console.log`.

---

Same way,

```
var style = (
  _style = {},
  _style[namespace + 'box-sizing'] = 'border-box',
  _style[namespace + 'box-shadow'] = '10px 10px 5px #888888',
  _style
);
```

Here,

```
  _style = {},
```

creates an object and assigns it to `_style`,

```
  _style[namespace + 'box-sizing'] = 'border-box',
```

creates a new property `namespace + 'box-sizing'` and assigns a value to it,

```
  _style[namespace + 'box-shadow'] = '10px 10px 5px #888888',
```

same as above, and finally, `_style` will be returned as the result of evaluation.

At the end, you get an object with two properties and that is bound to the variable `style`.

Comment: Aha.. `the expressions in parenthesis are executed from left-right` - are the parenthesis necessary for this I wonder. Thanks for the answer!